# Inner join in create stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

So, I have a `posts` table and I want to join `users`.. it is basically load on click thing.

I already have posts load on click but I can't figure out how to join `fk_user_id` from `posts` with `users` table and column `user_id`

I tried this, but do not work.

```
SELECT top (@posval) *
FROM dbo.posts
INNER JOIN dbo.users ON posts.fk_user_id = users.user_id
```

and then I have yet to create count select procedure, which I have not even start working on yet because of the first problem

this is the 2nd one tho

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.posts
```

Comment: "do not work". In what sense, does your computer starts smoking and your keyboard keys fly around the room, or do you actually get an error message?

Comment: @zoubida13 When I try to for example <%# Eval("user_name") %>, nothing shows up

Comment: Show us the full code then please, otherwise it's a bit hard to help you blindly debug it.

Comment: Inner join seems written well, make sure, that variable `@posval` is greater than `0` and in table `posts` are any data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT [your columns]
  FROM dbo.posts AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.users AS u
  ON p.fk_user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: I'm sorry guys, problem was it html. I haven't closed a href tag and that is why it didn't read the user_name for example D:. I'm so bad ._ .. And it took me like 3 hours..should I just delete post ._ .?

Comment: You really should use ANSI-92 style joins. It has been around for over 20 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: This answer offers no improvement over the original query in the question, except a lack of ANSI compliance.

Comment: i have re written it, please let me know guys if it is correct.